# How to build the yeoman "angular-generator" app in production?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I created my angular application with "yeoman" using "yo angular" with grunt sass bootstrap.

But with node_mudules bower_component and all dev feature the empty project is 200mo sized

How can I build my application for production, include minify css/js and keep only used and required dependance.

**EDIT**

I don't understand the -1, thousand people use the angular-generator from yeoman and I can't find a build tutorial **for this specific generator.**

`grunt build` seems to work but the website is not displaying well.

`grunt serve:dist` build and run on serve but same problem as `grunt build`

The dev application ( it s just `yo angular` empty project )

After `grunt serve`, it works and i can navigate

[image]

After `grunt serve:dist`, it doesn't work and i can't navigate, it seems like "bower_components" are not build well

[image]

Comment: why you want to build yeoman? you can directly install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using grunt do: "grunt build" or "grunt serve:dist", after the build you will get a dist folder, everything inside is you production app included minify css/js, you don't need anymore. And specify that for unknow reason "yo angular" add jquery to "devDependencies" but not in "dependencies"
in bower.json in you project.

You do not need to deploy everything from your project folder. Hope it help.

Comment: grunt build create a dist folder, but the website does not display well.

Comment: ok, include/import in your index.html any images or JS that you project depends on. Check the index.html.

Comment: does not display well.-- you need to check and post the console log with the errors.

Comment: to test you project you can do: 'grunt serve' and this will run a dev server env, if this works prod env should also works.

Comment: yes yes, "grunt serve" works of course there is a screenshot on the question. but "grunt serve:dist" doesn't works, it's the point of the question ! all is fine in development, now i wan't deploy in production just as "grunt build" or "grunt serve:dist" did but it doesn't work ( cf screenshot and log )

Comment: OK, grunt serve:dist show you project, nice; when I meant the console log and meant the console from firefox/chrome XD no the OS terminal.(sorry).Because it seems like you app has some errors loading.

Comment: Oh yes, mmmh, seems "grunt build" don't compile jquery. "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3"

Comment: Not really, jquery and angular are in "bower_component" folder. It's all right with "grunt serve", there is no reason to have this error with "grunt serve:dist", the problem remain the same, bower doesn't build well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116294/discussion-between-victor-sosa-and-amdev).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deploy everything from your project folder. You can find info on this [page](http://yeoman.io/learning/deployment.html).

Answer (score 0):

Only files which you include/import in your index.html or css ( images or fonts ), are being used and tracked. Rest are all useless after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

run gulp --production. firts it will clean dist folder (if exist) then move the minified and uglified file there.